# Matching words in a string that appear together

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to match words in a string that appear together, irrespective of their order of appearance.

I've tried doing something really basic. It gives me the expected result but I have to match any number of words entered by the user.

Example: user wants to match **"great product"**

```
str="great product. affordable useful cool."
if (str.find("great product")) != -1 or (str.find("product great")) != -1:
       print(str)
```

Gives expected result.
Now, if user wants to check if the string has the words

```
"useful affordable cool"
```

in any order as long as they appear together.

**str** has those words and so, it must match.

How would I do that? Should I use regex?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.permutations` and `any`

**Ex:**

```
tolook = "useful affordable cool".split()
str_val = "great product. affordable useful cool."
if any(i in str_val for i in [" ".join(comb) for comb in permutations(tolook, len(tolook))]):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("N\A")

#--->Found
```

Comment: Yup. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Rakesh!

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to handle this via a single regex, you could try using this pattern:

```
^(?=.*\buseful\b)(?=.*\baffordable\b)(?=.*\bcool\b).*$
```

Python script:

```
input = "great product. affordable useful cool."
match = re.match(r'^(?=.*\buseful\b)(?=.*\baffordable\b)(?=.*\bcool\b).*$', input)
if match:
    print("MATCH")
```

The regex pattern above makes use of positive *lookaheads*, each of which asserts that one of the keywords appears in the input string.  For example:

```
(?=.*\buseful\b)
```

asserts that `useful` appears.  The combination of the three lookaheads covers all three keywords.

Comment: if the position of your matches could also be somewhere within the string, use `re.search` instead and remove `^` since `re.match` starts matching at the very beginning of the string (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Comment: Exactly! I figured that out. I did that, but it's still not what I want. It matches for the occurrence of those words in the string. But I want them only if they occur together (and order not important). The  code given by Tim matches even if there are words between the user input words. Do you have a solution?

Comment: If you want to find literal `useful affordable cool`, then just search for `\buseful affordable cool\b`.  Am I missing something about your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tim. No, I do not want to match the exact literal. I want to match any combination of the literal. Basically, "useful affordable cool" = "cool affordable useful" = "affordable useful cool" etc.

Comment: @heisenberg My answer absolutely does this.  But the answer you accepted uses an easy to use API, and would scale better for an arbitrary number of search terms.

Comment: It does. But it also returns true for strings that have the substring with some other words in-between. Example: "useful some_other_word affordable cool".  I think my example in the question was a poor one. My bad